# How to use bootstrapping to compare two non-normal datasets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two data sets - one control and one treatment. I wish to test whether the difference between their means is significant or not (approx 30 data values in each set). The distributions of both of these data sets are definitely not normal.

I've looked into using the Mann Whitney U test however it seems that it is only useful for comparing distributions. I've read that it can compare median as well only if the distributions have the same shape except shifted, which is not the case.

Bootstrapping seems to be the best option. I was just wondering how to go about it for hypothesis testing? My idea has been to check if the means lie within one of the confidence intervals, however which group do I calculate the CI for? Do I calculate a CI for the true mean of the control group and compare with the bootstrapped mean of the treatment? Or do I calculate a CI for the treatment and see if the bootstrapped mean for the control lies within it?

Or do I calculate a CI for the control, and then check if the **sample mean** lies within the CI? Just a bit confused!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Correction: a t-test assumes that the difference of the two samples is normally distributed, not that each variable is normally distributed. If this assumption is not met then the Mann Whitney U test can be used as a non-parametric alternative. This test can be used to determine whether two independent samples were selected from populations having the same distribution. This is intentional, as comparing means of non-normal distributions is a little contentious, since it does not have the same meaning anymore as in normally distributed data. So I would use this over bootstrap.

Regardless, if you would still like to go with the bootstrap variant, I would not use bootstrap but rather a permutation test for hypothesis testing, which is a better option.